# Обособленный и необособленный оборот

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли эти запятые? Я думаю, нет, так как в этих деепричастных оборотах весь смысл предложении. Ударение падает на них – обороты эти.

1. – Как можно узнать, какой у меня ранг?

– Мы можете узнать(,) войдя в свой профил(,) ваш ранг.

2. Как слова эти написать?

– Вам надо их написать(,) вставляя пропущенные буквы.

3. – А вы(,) мокрой являясь(,) домой пришли?

– Нет, я когда пришла, уже высохла-таки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы оформила текст таким образом:

(1) – ***Как** можно узнать, какой у меня ранг?*

*– Вы можете узнать ваш рАнг, **войдя** в свой прОфиль.*

Другой вариант: *Вы можете узнать ваш рАнг,  если/когда  **войдете**  в свой прОфиль.*

(2) – **Как** слова эти написать?

*– Вам надо их написать, предварительно **вставив**  пропущенные буквы.*

Также: *Вам надо их записать  с уже **вставленными**  буквами.*

(3) *– А вы, **мОкрой являясь**, домОй пришли?*

*– Нет, я когда пришлА, **уже высОхла-таки.***

**Пояснение**

1. Смысл предложения в том, чтобы **корректно ответить** на заданный вопрос.
2. Если деепричастный оборот  выражает **смысл предложения** (является ответом на заданный вопрос), то он занимает **ударную позицию** в предложении, при этом он может быть обособленным или необособленным.
3. Обособленный деепричастный оборот (полупредикативная конструкция)  по смыслу равнозначен **придаточному предложению** (предикативной конструкции). Это разные синтаксические формы для записи определенного содержания.
4. Ту же семантику можно выразить и в простом предложении с **предложным словосочетанием**  (обособленным или необособленным).
5. Обособленные обороты выражают **дополнительную предикацию** по отношению к основной, то есть это дополнительный **смысловой центр** (семантическое и интонационное подчеркивание).
6. **Необособленный**  деепричастный оборот является  обстоятельством образа действия в простом предложении. В конце предложения он находится в ударной позиции.

Comment: То есть даже несмотря на то, что во всех предложениях деепричастный оборот – это то, что несёт главный смысл, и без него предложение не имело бы смысла, который оно должно нести, нужна запятая всё равно? Просто Розенталь говорит, что, если деепричастный оборот – это смысл предложения главный, запятая не ставится.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Лучше слушайте Розенталя.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Смысловое  ударение падает на обособленный и необособленный оборот. Переход оборота в необособленное обстоятельство - это целая тема, там действуют различные факторы. А какое именно высказывание Розенталя вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Возможно, что Розенталь имел только в виду те случаи, где оборот имеет наречное значение, а у меня во всех предложениях значение не наречное. Я, однако, всё равно сомневаюсь, что в этом предложении надо ставить запятые, если я спрашиваю человека не о том, может ли он учить, а о том, может ли он это *по-английски* делать-таки: *А вы можете(,) по-английски говоря(,) немецкому учить?*

Comment: @Sharon Но не от ударения же зависит, обстоятельство или нет. Ударения каждый по-своему ставит. Зависит от смысла.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Здесь другая структура предложения А вы можете по-англИйски говоря, немЕцкому учить? Здесь противопоставление  английский - немецкий.  Обособления нет,  оборот в значении обстоятельства.  Ударение падает на оба слова.

Comment: Нужны запятые или нет?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Наречное значение тогда, когда подходит вопрос "как?".

Comment: @Sharon Вам следует пересмотреть эту тему. 1. Из-за повтора ударение не будет падать на первую часть. Повторяемое не требует ударения. 2. Обстоятельство или нет, определяется по смыслу, никак не по ударениям. 3. Обособление зависит от структуры, про что говорится у Розенталя. Обособляется, когда деепричастие и глагол разделены (например, подлежащим, как в примерах Розенталя).

Comment: У вас в 3 получается по ударениям, что спрашивают, туда ли пришли (*А вы домОй пришли?*). А задумано другое: *Домой пришли мокрой?*

Comment: @oleedd  Рекомендую вам не вмешиваться в разговор (это невежливо, даже дети знают). (2)  Не учить меня тому, что сами неясно понимаете. И желательно без "следует".  (3)  Отвечать на вопросы самостоятельно, а не в чужих ответах.  И тем более критиковать их. НАРУШАЕТЕ все правила сайта, какие только можно.

Comment: Просто вы не совсем верно понимаете эту тему. Мы и раньше её обсуждали, поэтому не могу пройти мимо. Это уже и меня касается. Вы считаете, что ударения прежде всего. Так быть не может, потому что каждый ставит ударения по-своему и тогда пунктуация будет хаотичной (каждый будет писать по своим ударениям, а не по правилам).

Comment: В ответах нельзя критиковать другие ответы! Ответы для ответов, а не для критики. Критика неприятна, но очень полезна. Вам на благо. Не злитесь :) Просто надо смириться, что интонационный принцип не является ведущим. Иначе в справочниках была бы лишь одна строчка: "Ставим знаки по ударениям и паузам". Тогда было бы всё просто, но был бы хаос.

Comment: @oleedd  До свидания.   Ударение будем обсуждать в соответствующих темах.  (Смириться - смешное слово))  Я нашала нужный мне источник по интонации и  ударениям, когда вы еще и не слышали о них.

Comment: Где же ссылка на ваш источник (доказательство)? Очередной лингвистический беспредел. В вашем ответе ударения, поэтому обсуждаем. Вы ставите их выше смысла, это неверно. Такого нет в правилах.

Comment: Беспредел как раз у вас, а не у меня.  Ладно, зайчик, пока...  (Видите, как я ласково с вами разговариваю)

Comment: У вас лингвистический беспредел. Вы пару лет назад рассуждали, второе действие или особенность действия. Тогда умнее были в этой теме. А потом вас переклинило. Вы сегодня натворили делов, не могу ласково.

Comment: Ты не можешь так говорить, нет, не можешь, я тебе запрещаю!))) Это всё от Великой любви.